# What is the functional interpretation of the Eigen vectors in PCA?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I'm not sure if I asked this question correctly. But it occurred to me that in PCA (aka SVD), we treat the data matrix as if it is a linear transformation by talking about its 'Eigen vectors/values' but Eigen vectors and values are implicitly supposed to define the behavior of a matrix as linear transformation, since it describes what happens when you transform special vectors with the matrix.

So could you explain to me how/if it is indeed valid to think of an arbitrary data matrix (e.g. an arbitrary data frame) as a linear transformation? Specifically when you have no intention of using it that way, and just want to do PCA on it...

Comment: ???   Any matrix multiplication **is** a linear transformation!  A(X+ Y)= AX+ AY and A(cX)= cAx.   It is a little harder to show that any linear transformation (on finite dimensional space) can be represented by a matrix.

Comment: I'm not talking about matrix multiplication I'm talking about any data matrix. I don't understand what Eigen vectors are supposed to represent in a matrix which is not intended to be used as a linear transformation.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are doing with matrices.   The whole point of matrices  is how they are multiplied!

Comment: The rank $p$ approximation obtained from the SVD of a matrix $X$ is the best rank $p$ approximation to $X$ in the sense of the operator norm and the Hilbert-Schmidt norm. So the SVD is useful for dimensionality reduction.

Comment: Also if the columns of $X$ are centered, then $\frac{1}{n - 1}X^T X$ is the sample covariance matrix. The singular values of $X$ are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $X^T X$.

Comment: @user247327 could you elaborate? I'm talking about the very common scenario where you have a numerical data frame (e.g. an SQL data table), which you convert into a matrix for the sake of performing PCA for dimensionality reduction.

In this case it should be clear why you have a matrix and why you need to do PCA. I think it should also be obvious you never intend to do matrix multiplication with your matrix derived from a data table... (at least in 90% of cases I wouldn't expect to do it)

Comment: @user247327 in other words what I'm doing with matrices is simply storing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Mason: Up to a factor $\frac{1}{n-1}\,$ the square matrix $C=X^\top X$ is the sample covariance matrix (provided the columns are centered). Since $C$ is symmetric it can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix $S$:
$$
D=S^\top CS\,.
$$
The columns of $S$ are the eigenvectors of $C$ and the diagonal elements are its eigenvalues. Obviously,
$$
S DS^\top=X^\top X\,.
$$
Lets write $\sqrt{D}={\rm diag}(\sqrt{d_1},\dots,\sqrt{d_n})\,.$ If $\boldsymbol{x}$ is a random vector whose elements are independent, have mean zero and variance one then the covariance matrix of
$$
\boldsymbol{y}=\sqrt{D}S^\top\boldsymbol{x}
$$
is easily seen to be $C=X^\top X\,.$ In other words:

- the functional interpretation of the eigenvectors $S$ of $C$ is how you must linearly combine independent RVs such that they have the *same* covariance as your data $X$.

The whole idea of PCA is to find a variable transformation that transforms the independent RVs $\boldsymbol{x}$ into linear combinations $\boldsymbol{y}$ that have the same covariance matrix as the original data.

In that context, the covariance matrix $C$ is not interesting as a linear map. In PCA it is more interesting to ask how many elements of $\boldsymbol{x}$ are needed to explain most of the variance of the data.

You should probably work on a realistic numerical example to get your head around it.

Comment: Thanks, so it sounds like it is unrelated to Eigen vector's property that they scale only by a scaler when transformed by the matrix?

Comment: @profPlum : See my edit.