# geometric interpretation of deviation vector in direction of an eigenvector (of a covariance matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, euclidean-geometry, inner-products

Let $D = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & \cdot \cdot \cdot & x_{1d}\\ 
\cdot \cdot \cdot & \\ 
\cdot \cdot \cdot & \\ 
 \cdot \cdot \cdot &\\ 
x_{N1} & \cdot \cdot \cdot  &  x_{Nd}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{1}\\ 
\cdot \cdot \cdot \\ 
\cdot \cdot \cdot \\ 
\cdot \cdot \cdot \\ 
X_{N}
\end{bmatrix}
$

whose columns (or variables) are
$\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11}\\ 
\cdot \cdot \cdot \\ 
\cdot \cdot \cdot \\ 
\cdot \cdot \cdot \\ 
x_{N1}
\end{bmatrix}, \cdot \cdot \cdot ,\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1d}\\ 
\cdot \cdot \cdot \\ 
\cdot \cdot \cdot \\ 
\cdot \cdot \cdot \\ 
x_{Nd}
\end{bmatrix}$

Let the mean associated with each variable in the data set D be given by the row vector
$\bar{\mu} = \begin{bmatrix}
\bar{\mu_{1}} &\cdot \cdot \cdot & \bar{\mu_{d}}
\end{bmatrix}$

Suppose that the covariance matrix associated with the dataset $D$ yields a set $E$ of eigenvectors (column vectors) $E = {E_{1}, ..., E_{d}}$, all of which are mutually orthogonal since the symmetry of the covariance matrix guarantees the orthogonality of the set $E$ and whose corresponding eigenvectors are $\lambda_{1}, \cdot \cdot \cdot \lambda_{d}$

What does, for a data point $X$,

$\sum_{j = 1}^{d}\frac{|X - \bar{\mu}|\cdot\vec{E_{j}}}{\lambda_{j}}$

tells me? particularly, I am interested to know what the projection of $|X - \bar{\mu}|$ in the direction of an arbitrary $j^{th}$ eigenvector tells me.

Comment: A more standard linear combination of the eigenvectors can be found in [this closely related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255797/what-is-the-functional-interpretation-of-the-eigen-vectors-in-pca/4256405#4256405).